# AutoMapper not calling AfterMap when mapping a dynamic proxy

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, dynamic-proxy, automapper-6

Let's say I've designed a class `A` and also I've designed a DTO class called `Dto`.

If `A` is a *dynamic proxy* generated with Castle DynamicProxy, AutoMapper won't fire `AfterMap`:

```
mappingConfig.CreateMap<Dto, A>()
.AfterMap
(
     (dto, a, resolutionContext) => 
     {
          // Stuff to do after automatic mapping has been already completed
     }
);

// This won't fire AfterMap
Mapper.Map(dto, aProxy);
```

In the other hand, if I run the following code, `AfterMap` will be called:

```
var a = new A();
Mapper.Map(dto, a);
```

Also, `MappingConfiguration` is configured to automatically register types:

```
config.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
```

Currently I'm using AutoMapper 6.0.2. **I can't figure out why this isn't working**.

### Update

After some trial-errors, It started to work once I commented out `config.CreateMisstingTypeMaps` or I set it to `false`.

I suspect that AutoMapper is creating a map between the DTO and `AProxy` (which is a type generated during run-time) and prioritizes that mapping over the `Dto` and `A` *as is*.

Thus, how may I configure AutoMapper to both create missing type maps and also support my scenario?

Comment: I can't repro this. Are you sure you're not using it in `ProjectTo`?

Comment: @GertArnold I don't think so, my exact code line is `Mapper.Map(dto, badge);`

Comment: @GertArnold In fact, I'm as surprised as you, because it was working right with other dto/entity mappings, and I can't find what's the actual difference (if exists)

Comment: @GertArnold Check my update, I found what was behind the issue, BTW the issue itself isn't 100% solved.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer did you solve this problem? I'm trying to Map an object generated with DynamicProxy but Automapper doesn't map any property. :(